Issue with SMTP Server Implementation: Getting an Error
I am trying to implement an SMTP server by following this article
Here is my server code:
import smtpd
import asyncore

class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print ('Receiving message from:', peer)
        print ('Message addressed from:', mailfrom)
        print ('Message addressed to  :', rcpttos)
        print ('Message length        :', len(data))
        return


server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 1025), None)
print ("Sever started ...")

asyncore.loop()

And here is my client code:
import smtplib
import email.utils
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Create the message
msg = MIMEText('This is the body of the message.')
msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Recipient', 'recipient@example.com'))
msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Author', 'author@example.com'))
msg['Subject'] = 'Simple test message'

server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect('127.0.0.1', 1025)

server.set_debuglevel(True) # show communication with the server
server.sendmail('author@example.com', ['recipient@example.com'], msg.as_string())

"""
try:
    server.sendmail('author@example.com', ['recipient@example.com'], msg.as_string())
finally:
    server.quit()
"""

I am getting the following error:
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: b'250-mvnd3x-VirtualBox\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 33554432\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250 HELP\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'mvnd3x-VirtualBox\nSIZE 33554432\n8BITMIME\nHELP'
send: 'mail FROM:<author@example.com> size=236\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
send: 'rcpt TO:<recipient@example.com>\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: b'354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>'
data: (354, b'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: b'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nTo: Recipient <recipient@example.com>\r\nFrom: Author <author@example.com>\r\nSubject: Simple test message\r\n\r\nThis is the body of the message.\r\n.\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_client_1.py", line 15, in <module>
    server.sendmail('author@example.com', ['recipient@example.com'], msg.as_string())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 895, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 573, in data
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 398, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

I have double-checked the code and followed the article closely, but I am still encountering this issue. Could anyone help me understand what might be going wrong and how to fix it?
